# How to show description in alert from fullcalendar V5

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar, alert

I am trying to show some info about an event from fullcalendar version 5. Everything is displayed except the description. It says: `undefined`. What i am doing wrong and how can i show the content of description in the alert?

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;
    alert('ID: ' + info.event.id + 'Title: ' + info.event.title + 'Start: ' + info.event.start  + 'Description: ' + info.event.description );
},
events: [
        {
          id: 'id_1111',
          title: 'All Day Event 1',
          start: '2021-04-01',        
          description: 'First description',
         
        },
        {
          id: 'id_2222',
          title: 'All Day Event 2',
          start: '2021-04-02',        
          description: 'Second description',
          
        }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extendedProps` for this accordign to the document: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object. Look under: **Non-standard Fields**

So:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;
    alert('ID: ' + info.event.id + 'Title: ' + info.event.title + 'Start: ' + info.event.start  + 'Description: ' + info.event.extendedProps.description );
},
events: [
        {
          id: 'id_1111',
          title: 'All Day Event 1',
          start: '2021-04-01',       
          description: 'First description',
         
        },
        {
          id: 'id_2222',
          title: 'All Day Event 2',
          start: '2021-04-02',        
          description: 'Second description',
          
        }
]
```